# How can I compare pairs of columns in a PySpark dataframe and number of records changed?

Tags: list, apache-spark, pyspark, compare, multiple-columns

I have a situation where I need to compare multiple pairs of columns (the number of pairs will vary and can come from a list as shown in below code snippet) and get 1/0 flag for match/mismatch respectively. Eventually use this to identify the number of records/rows with mismatch and % records mismatched

```py
NONKEYCOLS= ['Marks', 'Qualification']
```

The first image is *source df* and second image is *expected df*.

[image: Source DF]

[[image: Expected Results2]

[image]

Since this is happening for multiple pairs on a loop, it is very slow for about a billion records. Need help with something efficient.

I have the below code but the part that calculates change records is taking long time.

```
  for ind,cols in enumerate(NONKEYCOLS):
        print(ind)
        print(cols)
        globals()['new_dataset' + '_char_changes_tmp']=globals()['new_dataset' + '_char_changes_tmp']\
                                                       .withColumn("records_changed" + str(ind),\
                                                       F.sum(col("records_ch_flag_" + str(ind)))\
                                                       .over(w1))
    
        globals()['new_dataset' + '_char_changes_tmp']=globals()['new_dataset' + '_char_changes_tmp']\
                                                       .withColumn("records_changed" + str(ind),\
                                                       F.sum(col("records_ch_flag_" + str(ind)))\
                                                       .over(w1))
        globals()['new_dataset' + '_char_changes_tmp']=globals()['new_dataset' + '_char_changes_tmp']\
                                                       .withColumn("records_changed_cnt" + str(ind),\
                                                       F.count(col("records_ch_flag_" + str(ind)))\
                                                      .over(w1))
```

Comment: I can't imagine `when` condition being slow in this situation. Can you please show your implementation?

Comment: @ZygD, here is a rough implementation that takes a long time

Comment: Please share. It helps very much to see what you have done yourself, instead of simply asking to code for you. I mean, I may offer a solution, but if you already use that same solution, I would waste my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure what loop are you running, but here's an implementation with list comprehension within a `select`.

```py
data_ls = [
    (10, 11, 'foo', 'foo'),
    (12, 12, 'bar', 'bar'),
    (10, 12, 'foo', 'bar')
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['marks_1', 'marks_2', 'qualification_1', 'qualification_2'])

col_pairs = ['marks','qualification']

data_sdf. \
    select('*',
           *[(func.col(c+'_1') == func.col(c+'_2')).cast('int').alias(c+'_check') for c in col_pairs]
           ). \
    show()

# +-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------------------+
# |marks_1|marks_2|qualification_1|qualification_2|marks_check|qualification_check|
# +-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------------------+
# |     10|     11|            foo|            foo|          0|                  1|
# |     12|     12|            bar|            bar|          1|                  1|
# |     10|     12|            foo|            bar|          0|                  0|
# +-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

where the list comprehension would yield the following

```py
[(func.col(c+'_1') == func.col(c+'_2')).cast('int').alias(c+'_check') for c in col_pairs]
# [Column<'CAST((marks_1 = marks_2) AS INT) AS `marks_check`'>,
#  Column<'CAST((qualification_1 = qualification_2) AS INT) AS `qualification_check`'>]
```

---

*EDIT*

based on the additional (updated) info, you need the count of unmatched records for that pair and then you want to calculate the unmatched percentage.

reversing the aforementioned logic to count the unmatched records

```py
col_pairs = ['marks','qualification']

data_sdf. \
    agg(*[func.sum((func.col(c+'_1') != func.col(c+'_2')).cast('int')).alias(c+'_unmatch') for c in col_pairs],
        func.count('*').alias('row_cnt')
        ). \
    select('*',
           *[(func.col(c+'_unmatch') / func.col('row_cnt')).alias(c+'_unmatch_perc') for c in col_pairs]
           ). \
    show()

# +-------------+---------------------+-------+------------------+--------------------------+
# |marks_unmatch|qualification_unmatch|row_cnt|marks_unmatch_perc|qualification_unmatch_perc|
# +-------------+---------------------+-------+------------------+--------------------------+
# |            2|                    1|      3|0.6666666666666666|        0.3333333333333333|
# +-------------+---------------------+-------+------------------+--------------------------+
```

the code flags (as 1) the records where the pair does not match and takes a sum of the flag - which gives us the pair's unmatched record count. dividing that with the total row count will give the percentage.

the list comprehension will yield the following

```py
[func.sum((func.col(c+'_1') != func.col(c+'_2')).cast('int')).alias(c+'_unmatch') for c in col_pairs]
# [Column<'sum(CAST((NOT (marks_1 = marks_2)) AS INT)) AS `marks_unmatch`'>,
#  Column<'sum(CAST((NOT (qualification_1 = qualification_2)) AS INT)) AS `qualification_unmatch`'>]
```

this is very much efficient as all of it happens in a single `select` statement which will only project once in the spark plan as opposed to your approach which will project every time you do a `withColumn` - and that is inefficient to spark.

Comment: I have edited the question since i was mistaken about thinking that the when condition is taking long but actually it is the sum taking long

Comment: @PawanTolani - sum of what? could you please share the explanation around what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: it should be sum of total mismatched records. In the whole ddataframe 3 records have changed for marks and 2 for qualification. Then we go on to find the percentage records changed i.e 3/5*100 and 2.5*100 for marks and qualification respectively

Comment: @PawanTolani - i updated my answer to reflect your updated problem. note that i've used my sample input df and the results reflect outputs based on the same.

Comment: I implemented it and it worked fast in under a minute. However, I dont see the newly created columns. To verify this, I am going to assign it to another df

Comment: @PawanTolani - you should see them in the final df, if you've used exactly what i've stated. did you change anything? also, if you're assigning it to a new df, then you should remove the `show()`.

Comment: for ind,cols in enumerate(NONKEYCOLS):
        print(ind)
        print(cols)
        globals()['new_dataset' + '_char_changes_tmp']. \
    agg(*[func.sum((func.col(cols) != func.col(cols+'prev')).cast('int')).alias(cols+'_unmatch') for cols in NONKEYCOLS],
        func.count('*').alias('row_cnt')
        ). \
    select('*',
           *[(func.col(cols+'_unmatch') / func.col('row_cnt')).alias(cols+'_unmatch_perc') for cols in NONKEYCOLS]
           )

Comment: the whole point was to not use `for ind,cols in enumerate(NONKEYCOLS): ` -- the solution will work without any loops, also, what is `globals()['new_dataset' + '_char_changes_tmp']` signifying? a df? where is the result being assigned to? i don't see `df = other_df.agg()...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249263/discussion-between-pawan-tolani-and-samkart).

Answer (score 1):

[**`df.colRegex`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.colRegex.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.colRegex) may serve you well. If all the values in columns which match the regex are equal, you get 1. The script is efficient, as everything is done in one `select`.

Inputs:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('p', 1, 2, 'g', 'm'),
     ('a', 3, 3, 'g', 'g'),
     ('b', 4, 5, 'g', 'g'),
     ('r', 8, 8, 'm', 'm'),
     ('d', 2, 1, 'u', 'g')],
    ['Name', 'Marks_1', 'Marks_2', 'Qualification_1', 'Qualification_2'])

col_pairs = ['Marks', 'Qualification']
```

Script:

```py
def equals(*cols):
    return (F.size(F.array_distinct(F.array(*cols))) == 1).cast('int')

df = df.select(
    '*',
    *[equals(df.colRegex(f"`^{c}.*`")).alias(f'{c}_result') for c in col_pairs]
)

df.show()
# +----+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+------------+--------------------+
# |Name|Marks_1|Marks_2|Qualification_1|Qualification_2|Marks_result|Qualification_result|
# +----+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+------------+--------------------+
# |   p|      1|      2|              g|              m|           0|                   0|
# |   a|      3|      3|              g|              g|           1|                   1|
# |   b|      4|      5|              g|              g|           0|                   1|
# |   r|      8|      8|              m|              m|           1|                   1|
# |   d|      2|      1|              u|              g|           0|                   0|
# +----+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Proof of efficiency:

```py
df.explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Project [Name#636, Marks_1#637L, Marks_2#638L, Qualification_1#639, Qualification_2#640, cast((size(array_distinct(array(Marks_1#637L, Marks_2#638L)), true) = 1) as int) AS Marks_result#646, cast((size(array_distinct(array(Qualification_1#639, Qualification_2#640)), true) = 1) as int) AS Qualification_result#647]
# +- Scan ExistingRDD[Name#636,Marks_1#637L,Marks_2#638L,Qualification_1#639,Qualification_2#640]
```

*Edit:*

```py
def equals(*cols):
    return (F.size(F.array_distinct(F.array(*cols))) != 1).cast('int')

df = df.select(
    '*',
    *[equals(df.colRegex(f"`^{c}.*`")).alias(f'{c}_result') for c in col_pairs]
).agg(
    *[F.sum(f'{c}_result').alias(f'rec_changed_{c}') for c in col_pairs],
    *[(F.sum(f'{c}_result') / F.count(f'{c}_result')).alias(f'{c}_%_rec_changed') for c in col_pairs]
)
df.show()
# +-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
# |rec_changed_Marks|rec_changed_Qualification|Marks_%_rec_changed|Qualification_%_rec_changed|
# +-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
# |                3|                        2|                0.6|                        0.4|
# +-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: I have edited the question since i was mistaken about thinking that the when condition is taking long but actually it is the sum taking long

Comment: Please take a look at the edit